# How can I determine the current config of php-fpm?

Tags: php, fpm

I'd like to determine the current config that is 'loaded'. These would be all the values listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

These values are not returned by `phpinfo()`.

Comment: example : /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf

Comment: do they return with `ini_get_all()` or `ini_get(...)`?

Comment: also, what problem are you trying to solve exactly? what are you going to do when you get the values?

Comment: This is a good question. I don't see **max_children** anywhere in the `php -i` output. I've also tried checking with `ini_get('pm')` and it returns FALSE.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you have access to server, try, depending on php version

```
sudo php-fpm7.0 -tt
sudo php-fpm7.x -tt
sudo php-fpm7.4 -tt
```

```
sudo php-fpm8.0 -tt
sudo php-fpm8.1 -tt
sudo php-fpm8.2 -tt
```

It test the current config file and show config params values (also default ones).

The **displayed values can differs from current running config** if a modification happened and php-fpm hasn't been reloaded.

Only tested out on php-fpm 8.1

Note: Output from the command goes to standard error and that makes piping to something like `grep` or `less` inconvenient. To account for this:

```
php-fpm8.2 -tt 2>&1 | grep access
```

Comment: Emphasis on: "The `displayed values` can differs from `current running config` if a modification happened and php-fpm hasn't been reloaded."

Comment: `php-fpm7.4: command not found`

Comment: you should try to find out which php version you're using first @Avatar

Comment: Within a Docker container based on a `php:x.x.x-fpm` image no need to specify the version just type `php-fpm -tt`.

Comment:  it doesn't need `sudo` and probably doesn't need version number❗— If on a server with a single specific version installed, the command to run is 90% of the times: `php-fpm -tt`.

Answer (score 14):

There are two ways to check it out, as far as I know

1. use ps command to locate the fpm config file and read it

```
root@c56686e9854c:/# ps aux | grep php-fpm  | grep master
```

> root  1 0.0  0.9 455112 37324 ? Ss 12:01 0:00 php-fpm: master process
>   (***/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf***)

2. use php-fpm's own command

```
root@c56686e9854c:/# php-fpm -tt
```

> [29-Mar-2020 12:31:23] NOTICE: [www]
>
> ...
>
> [29-Mar-2020 12:31:23] NOTICE: pm = dynamic
>
> [29-Mar-2020 12:31:23] NOTICE:  pm.max_children = 5
>
> [29-Mar-2020 12:31:23] NOTICE:  pm.start_servers = 2
>
> [29-Mar-2020 12:31:23] NOTICE:  pm.min_spare_servers = 1
>
> [29-Mar-2020 12:31:23] NOTICE:  pm.max_spare_servers = 3
>
> ...

Comment: `php-fpm: command not found`

Answer (score 8):

Axi's solution is not complete, in that the -tt flag merely displays the values of the current config files as they exist on the filesystem, not the values that are *currently* loaded into memory. These values may not necessarily be the same. For example, if an edit was made to the file, but fpm was not reloaded.

The best solution I found was to enable the FPM Status Page in Apache or Nginx. Although it doesn't display all variables, it's better than nothing.

Comment: I added a precision on my post as it seems it wasn't clear enough

Comment: Sadly, even this doesn't show the runtime configuration for "pm.max_children" or "pm.min_spare_servers", for example.

Answer (score -4):

You can use:

```
parse_ini_file(php_ini_loaded_file())
```

Comment: This doesn't show you settings like pm.max_children or pm.min_spare_servers, pm.max_spare_servers, etc.